# dvisvgm: DVI to SVG issue

Tags: svg, dvi, dvisvgm

I am trying to convert a DVI to SVG on Manjaro / Arch Linux, but it just won't work.

I use the following latex (test.tex) to create a dvi file (test.div)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\r{2cm}
  \node (O) at (0,0) {$O$};
  \draw (0,0) circle (\r);
  \draw[->] (-\r,0)--(\r,0);
  \draw[->] (0,-\r)--(0,\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile test.tex to dvi with the command line below:

```
latex test.tex
```

Create an SVG from the created test.div file.

```
dvisvgm test.dvi
```

Now I get the following error message:

```
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)

 *** WARNING - you have selected SAFER, indicating you want Ghostscript
               to execute in a safer environment, but at the same time
               have selected DELAYBIND. Unless you use this option with
               care (and specifically, remember to call .bindnow) it is
               possible that malicious code may be able to evade the
               limited security offered by the SAFER option.

 *** WARNING - you have selected SAFER, indicating you want Ghostscript
               to execute in a safer environment, but at the same time
               have selected WRITESYSTEMDICT. Unless you use this option with
               care and specifically, remember to execute code like:
                      "systemdict readonly pop"
           processing page 1
  PostScript error: undefined in get
  Operand stack:
      --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  --nostringval--  1  1  --nostringval--  .setopacityalpha
```

Ghostscript is installed.

Comment: You probably use Ghostscript 9.50 together with a dvisvgm version < 2.8.Older versions of dvisvgm don't work with the latest GS due to incompatible changes of the latter. You either must update dvisvgm or downgrade Ghostscript to get rid of the mentioned PostScript errors.

Comment: You're right, my dvisvgm version is 2.6.3. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. :-)